# if -else in shell script, matching argument with string

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables

For the following shell script -

```
#!/bin/sh
main_version=0
feature_version=0
patch_version=0
if [[ $1 -eq "m" ]]; then
    main_version=$((main_version+1))
fi

if [[ $1 -eq "f" ]]; then
    feature_version=$((feature_version+1))
fi

if [[ $1 -eq "p" ]]; then
    patch_version=$((patch_version+1))
fi

echo $main_version
echo $feature_version
echo $patch_version
```

It is incrementing all the variables even though i pass `m` as argument using `./<script-name>.sh m`

What is the reason for that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-eq` uses arithmetic comparison. Sh arithmetic operations treat non-numeric operands as 0, so you're just checking `[[ 0 -eq 0 ]]` in all three cases.

For string comparison you want `[ "x" = "y" ]` instead. (That's the POSIX shell syntax.)

The Bash syntax is `[[ x == y ]]` with double =, but it is *not a good idea* to use bashisms/kshisms when your script header declares /bin/sh. Either change the header to require Bash, or stick to only POSIX shell syntax.